# ncurses clear() causes flickering

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm using ncurses for a typing game I'm making. Letters fall down the screen and you must type them before they reach the bottom. It's working great, save one problem. Clearing the window (with clear()) makes the output flicker. I put clear() at the very beginning of the loop and wrefresh() at the very end. Shouldn't it be waiting 'til wrefresh to show anything, thus not flashing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <curses.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

  srand(time(NULL));

  //input character integer (ASCII)
  int ch = 1;
  //int to store the last time the character positions were updated
  int lastupdate = time(NULL);

  //x,y,char arrays for falling characters and initialization
  int chars[10], x[10], y[10];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    chars[i] = rand()%25 + 97;
    x[i] = rand()%30;
    y[i] = 0;
    //y[i] = -(rand()%4);
  }

  while (true){
    clear();
    ch = wgetch(stdscr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      mvwdelch(stdscr,y[i]-1,x[i]);//delete char's prev. position
      mvwaddch(stdscr, y[i], x[i], chars[i]);//add char's current position
      if (ch == chars[i]){
        mvwdelch(stdscr, y[i], x[i]);
        chars[i] = rand()%25 + 97;
        x[i] = rand()%30;
        y[i] = 0;
      }
    }

    if(time(0) >= (lastupdate + 1)){
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        y[i]++;
      }
      lastupdate = time(NULL);
    }

    wmove(stdscr, 20, 0);
    printw("your score is NULL. press ESC to exit");

    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    wrefresh(stdscr);
  }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

edit: added code

edit2: removed some irrelevant debug code

Comment: If you are using ncurses, you shouldn't need to do a wrefresh every cycle through the loop.  That's inefficient, and will cause... flicker.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. There's no flicker at all if clear() isn't used, even if wrefresh is called every cycle.

Comment: Oops, I meant clear not wrefresh.  Luckily, that's been explained well in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wgetch()` just after the `clear()` does an implicit `wrefresh()`. From the `wgetch()` man page:

```
If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified
since the last call to wrefresh, wrefresh will be called before
another character is read.
```

Answer (score 14):

I suggest to Just use erase() instead of clear()
clear also calls clearok() automatically.

Answer (score 7):

The [`clear`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html) manual page is the place to start:

> The  **`clear`** and **`wclear`** routines are like **`erase`** and **`werase`**, but they also
>   call clearok, so that the screen is cleared completely on the next call
>   to **`wrefresh`** for that window and ***repainted from scratch***.

The [**`wgetch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) call does that **`wrefresh`**, which causes the repainting:

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the
>          last call to **`wrefresh`**, **`wrefresh`** will be called before another character
>          is read.

The description of `wrefresh` is not nearly so succinct, but "repainting from scratch" will cause flickering since there is a moment when the screen is empty, followed by it being non-empty.  Those alternate rapidly due to this call:

```
nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
```